# Forcing BLE advertisements to use a public mac address

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to simulate a ble beacon, and I'm successfully able to broadcast advertisements but I have not found a way to force the advertisements to use a public address. I'm working with a device that will only listen for beacons with a static and public MAC address (I cannot control this, as annoying as it is). Is there any platform or library that would allow me to set/spoof the MAC so that the listening device believes it is a static public MAC? I have access to linux, android, and windows machines and can develop in pretty much whatever language I need to to achieve this.

Comment: What platform are you using? This is an expected privacy feature of BLE, and not all BLE stacks actually let you disable this.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this on Linux through the following sequence:-

```
#sudo btmgmt power off
#sudo btmgmt privacy off
#sudo btmgmt power on
```

Then launch bluetoothctl and start advertising:-

```
#bluetoothctl
[bluetoothctl] advertise on
```

You can scan for your device using any app on Android (e.g. nRF Connect) and double check that it is the static/public address through Linux using the command:-

```
[bluetoothctl] show
```

I hope this helps.